# How to put the email signature at the bottom in replies?

Tags: iphone, ios, email

I'm facing a strange problem on my iPhone with the email signature in a reply. Whenever I send a new email, the signature appears at the bottom of the new mail (as it should be):

```
<some mail content>

-- 
Company
Name
Phone Number
```

So everything looks good. However, when I reply to or forward a mail, the signature appears right in the middle:

```
<Here is where the cursor stands>

-- 
Company
Name
Phone Number

<Original email>
```

That means, that the original mail has gotten part of the signature and I manually need to cut & paste the signature to the end of the mail. After wasting an hour of searching google, I still can't find a solution for this. So does anyone here know how to fix this?

Comment: Surely that's correct behaviour... your signature goes below your contribution, not the quoted content.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope your contribution should be interspersed with the original and signature at the bottom :)

Comment: This may be a cultural difference, then. I'd never dream of it.

Comment: Depends wether you started on Unix mail or cc-mail/Microsoft

Comment: The signature concept is coming from the written legacy. In a document a signature should be at the end, might the content come from your own writing or quoted from another writing you are replying to. •••• When you are seeking the signature of a document or an E-mail, you seek to the end of the text. •••• Software respectful of this normal practice as `Thunderbird` let you the freedom to put your signature in a *normal* place. Other software as `Outlook` don't give this freedom.

Comment: Seems like this is still the same religious fight than it was ten years ago. Thank you for your answers. I'm giving up on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Mail app on your iPhone does not allow for the positioning of your signature to be altered. Oddly, the Apple Mail app on your Mac **does** allow for that.

There are alternative email applications on the iPhone which do allow this to be configured. [AirMail](http://airmailapp.com/ios) is one of them. At $5, it's not a free application.

Comment: Alternatively, you could achieve the required result using an AppleScript. But I'm not sure how comfortable you are with this.

Comment: How do you use AppleScript on an iPhone??